# Setting timeout for wininet in Loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner, wininet

This question for the times when you have to use WinInet replay engine in loadrunner. A timeout error is observed when the response time is more than 30 seconds. By default wininet has timeout set to 30 seconds. There is a way to make it retry the request but in my situation it's a post request and retry is not a realistic case.
Error encountered is -

```
Error -27492: "HttpSendRequest" failed, Windows error code=12002 and retry limit (0) exceeded for URL="https
```

**Screenshot of RTS:**

[image]

**Is there a way to configure the timeout to higher value and where to do it?**

LR12.53, Windows server 2008

### New Information

To demonstrate above behaviour, I have created a web app which takes more than 30 seconds to respond to a GET request. I have also enabled WinInet replay in runtime settings in Loadrunner like shown in above diagram.

**Action of the script**

```
Action()
{
lr_start_transaction("slow_transaction");

web_custom_request("slow_transaction",
    "URL=http://localhost:8887/slow_response",
    "Method=GET",
    "TargetFrame=",
    "Resource=0",
    "Referer=",
    "Mode=HTML",
    "Body=",
    LAST);

lr_end_transaction("slow_transaction", LR_AUTO);

return 0;
}
```

On execution of above script with advanced trace, I can see following logs. Error observed is `Action.c(6): Error -27492: "HttpSendRequest" failed, Windows error code=12002 and retry limit (0) exceeded for URL="http://localhost:8887/slow_response"    [MsgId: MERR-27492]`

```
Action.c(4): Notify: Transaction "slow_transaction" started.
Action.c(6): web_custom_request("slow_transaction") started     [MsgId: MMSG-26355]
Action.c(6): DETECTING_PROXY" on behalf of "URL="http://localhost:8887/slow_response"   [MsgId: MMSG-27397]
Action.c(6): RESOLVING_NAME" on behalf of "URL="http://localhost:8887/slow_response"    [MsgId: MMSG-27397]
Action.c(6): NAME_RESOLVED" on behalf of "URL="http://localhost:8887/slow_response"     [MsgId: MMSG-27397]
Action.c(6): CONNECTING_TO_SERVER" on behalf of "URL="http://localhost:8887/slow_response"      [MsgId: MMSG-27397]
Action.c(6): CONNECTING_TO_SERVER" on behalf of "URL="http://localhost:8887/slow_response"      [MsgId: MMSG-27397]
Action.c(6): CONNECTED_TO_SERVER" on behalf of "URL="http://localhost:8887/slow_response"   [MsgId: MMSG-27397]
Action.c(6): SENDING_REQUEST" on behalf of "URL="http://localhost:8887/slow_response"   [MsgId: MMSG-27397]
Action.c(6): REQUEST_SENT" on behalf of "URL="http://localhost:8887/slow_response"      [MsgId: MMSG-27397]
Action.c(6): RECEIVING_RESPONSE" on behalf of "URL="http://localhost:8887/slow_response"    [MsgId: MMSG-27397]
Action.c(6): CLOSING_CONNECTION" on behalf of "URL="http://localhost:8887/slow_response"    [MsgId: MMSG-27397]
Action.c(6): CONNECTION_CLOSED" on behalf of "URL="http://localhost:8887/slow_response"     [MsgId: MMSG-27397]
Action.c(6): REQUEST_COMPLETE" on behalf of "URL="http://localhost:8887/slow_response"      [MsgId: MMSG-27397]
Action.c(6): Error -27492: "HttpSendRequest" failed, Windows error code=12002 and retry limit (0) exceeded for URL="http://localhost:8887/slow_response"    [MsgId: MERR-27492]
Action.c(6): HANDLE_CLOSING" on behalf of "URL="http://localhost:8887/slow_response"    [MsgId: MMSG-27397]
Action.c(6): web_custom_request("slow_transaction") highest severity level was "ERROR", 0 body bytes, 0 header bytes    [MsgId: MMSG-26388]
Action.c(6): Notify: Transaction "slow_transaction" ended with a "Fail" status (Duration: 31.1355 Wasted Time: 0.1075).
```

Now on setting retry with `web_set_max_retries("2");` in the script, we can clearly see in the logs that it is retrying it after sometime when response doesn't arrive but this will fail too as its a new request and will again take more than 30 seconds ;)

**Logs for retry:**

```
Action.c(7): CLOSING_CONNECTION" on behalf of "URL="http://localhost:8887/slow_response"    [MsgId: MMSG-27397]
Action.c(7): CONNECTION_CLOSED" on behalf of "URL="http://localhost:8887/slow_response"     [MsgId: MMSG-27397]
Action.c(7): REQUEST_COMPLETE" on behalf of "URL="http://localhost:8887/slow_response"      [MsgId: MMSG-27397]
Action.c(7): Attempting "HttpSendRequest" retry due to Windows error code=12002 for URL="http://localhost:8887/slow_response"   [MsgId: MMSG-27491]
Action.c(7): DETECTING_PROXY" on behalf of "URL="http://localhost:8887/slow_response"   [MsgId: MMSG-27397]
Action.c(7): CONNECTING_TO_SERVER" on behalf of "URL="http://localhost:8887/slow_response"      [MsgId: MMSG-27397]
Action.c(7): CONNECTED_TO_SERVER" on behalf of "URL="http://localhost:8887/slow_response"   [MsgId: MMSG-27397]
```

Now that we have evidence of WinInet retrying after about 30 seconds. Can I please request HP support or other LR experts, WinInet experts to suggest if there is a way to increase the timeout in WinInet and how?

Comment: Please clarify how you know this to be a Windows Integrated Identity and Security issue which requires a retry

Comment: Hi James, I dont want it to retry the request, want it to wait for more time (synchronous). Its because some of my applications take longer than 30 seconds (it is accepted) to respond and in this case LRs default playback (sockets) doesnt work. Been observing other issues with that. That's entirely a different question. So simply put, need a way to increase the WinInet Default timeout which is 30 seconds.

Comment: Standard HTTP timeout is 120 seconds.  This means not so much as a single byte is returned inside of that window.  Are you certain you are not looking at connection timeout, which is different than response timeout?

Comment: hi all, I have added new information and evidence of lr timeout while using wininet replay engine. Please read the question again.

Comment: You are on localhost.  You should not be using a proxy for connection

Comment: As you are using WinInet LoadRunner does not control the network setting, none the run-time settings will have any impact on the timeout, this is controlled by Internet Explorer. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/mobile/mcsf/wininet-receivetimeout-duration on how to set this.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same issue as yours.
Due to using Wininet replay, all runtime setting will not affect to the running test.

We have to set the Wininet registry to allow timeout more than 30 seconds by going to

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
> Settings

**Add new DWORD key and value** (I set to 10 minutes)

> - Key: ReceiveTimeout
> - Value: 600000

Comment: This should be added to the web servers or servers with load generators or the one with controller?

Comment: This setting should be set on the client.  Therefore, I have written the vugen script to add the registry setting in the first step for each run.

Answer (score 0):

Actualy, the WinInet replay engine has nothing to do with setting the timeout parameter in runtime settings.

There are 2 places you need to change it:

1. Runtime settings > Internet Protocol > Preferences > General > "Step download timeout":

[image]

---

2. Runtime settings > Internet Protocol > Preferences > HTTP > "HTTP request connect timeout", "HTTP request receive timeout" and "HTTP Keep Alive timeout":

[image]

Comment: Ask yourself, if you really have not received so much as a single byte of response inside of the default timeout of 120 seconds, is it really advisable to change the timeout to a higher value?  I would be willing to bet that a two minute non-response would be considered not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting to the local host, i.e., the same machine.  You should not be sending your items through a Proxy for a local machine connection.  Turn off any proxy settings.

Next, you are on a local machine.  This makes the network cost zero as you will simply be bouncing through the bottom of the stack and back up, never hitting the network interface card nor exiting the box. This means the timeout is explicitly not related to network and has to be a configuration issue on the target service on your local machine.

As you are signed into Localhost and you are connecting to localhost, your security context for any execution should be your credentials where you are signed into localhost.  I still do not see how this is a windows integrated authentication issue in your code, but if it is and your target service is fully integrated with a Windows security context, then consider that you may need a few header fields with your security credential information.

Comment: James, I believe this answer is off topic. I wrote that application myself to deliberately delay the response to demonstrate LR behavior when using WinInet replay engine and I have set LR to not use any proxy in RTS. The application is running on my local machine and I am not using any proxy.  I believe the logs related to proxy is appearing due to enabling advanced trace. Let me know if you think otherwise. Once again, this question is not about proxy settings or using a localhost. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to all the WINDOWS machine. Press "Windows+R" , this will open up the RUN window. Enter "regedit.exe. Click HKEY_CURRENT_USER

Expand this and reach up-to: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\InternetSetting

On the Edit menu, go to New, and then click DWORD Value.

Type KeepAliveTimeout, and press ENTER.

Follow Step 2

Type ReceiveTimeout, and press ENTER.

Follow Step 2 Type SendTimeout, and press ENTER.

On the Edit menu, click Modify.

Enter the time-out value (in milliseconds), and then click OK. For example, to set the time-out value to one minutes, enter 60000. Restart the machine.

You can also refer here for more details - [wininet replay fail](https://blogger.askyourwebsite.com/wininet-replay-fail/)